# npm outdated error Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: node.js, npm

I try running 'npm outdated' from the console in my node project. But I get this error:

```
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-31T12_26_30_745Z-debug.log
```

This is the error in the log:

```
199 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
199 verbose stack     at dotindex (C:\Users\amita\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\text-table\index.js:59:32)
199 verbose stack     at C:\Users\amita\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\text-table\index.js:11:21
199 verbose stack     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
199 verbose stack     at forEach (C:\Users\amita\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\text-table\index.js:73:31)
199 verbose stack     at C:\Users\amita\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\text-table\index.js:10:9
199 verbose stack     at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
199 verbose stack     at reduce (C:\Users\amita\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\text-table\index.js:63:30)
199 verbose stack     at module.exports (C:\Users\amita\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\text-table\index.js:9:20)
199 verbose stack     at C:\Users\amita\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\outdated.js:130:16
199 verbose stack     at cb (C:\Users\amita\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\async-map.js:47:24)
199 verbose stack     at outdated_ (C:\Users\amita\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\outdated.js:221:12)
199 verbose stack     at skip (C:\Users\amita\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\outdated.js:343:5)
199 verbose stack     at updateDeps (C:\Users\amita\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\outdated.js:446:7)
199 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Users\amita\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
199 verbose stack     at Promise.successAdapter [as _fulfillmentHandler0] (C:\Users\amita\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\nodeify.js:23:30)
199 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\amita\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:566:21)
200 verbose cwd C:\Users\amita\Ionic\toratlechima
201 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
202 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\amita\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "outdated"
203 verbose node v10.11.0
204 verbose npm  v6.9.0
205 error Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
206 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

This also happens when I try to run it globally.
Anyone encounter this?

Comment: I've got this as well

Comment: you can use https://nodejs.org/en/download/ this worked for me

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Appears to be fixed in the next release, which isn't out yet.

https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/173

You can install the pre-release to fix it.

`npm -g i npm@next`

**Update**

NPM 6.9.2 is out

`npm install -g npm`

Comment: tried both commands and got `pm WARN tar zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
npm ERR! zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null`

Comment: @Mobigital try 'nvm install node'

Answer (score 12):

There is a bug in the npm, but you can easily fix it:

1. Go to your `npm` folder (i.e. `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`) and find a `outdated.js` file (i.e. `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/outdated.js` for **Mac** or `C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\outdated.js` for **Windows**)
2. Find a function `makePretty` and change

   ```
   deppath
   ```

   to

   ```
   deppath || 'global'
   ```

in my case it was line #152

I hope it helps!

Comment: I already have deppath || 'global' there, but still fails with zlib length issue :-/

Answer (score 2):

You can also try `npm upgrade -g`. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I successfully fixed the error after checking 'global' was in outdated.js file.  **Without any other requirements** like brew etc, (type these commands in the terminal):

1. `sudo npm cache clean -f` (force) clear you npm cache
2. `sudo npm install -g n` install *n* (this might take a while)
3. `sudo n stable` upgrade to the current stable version
4. `npm upgrade -g` upgrade npm

*Note that `sudo` might prompt your password.*